# How do I use colons and punctuation in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, syntactic-analysis, capitalization

Should I use a colon before a list? Which of the following is correct?

> I’ll never forget that night when I sat staring at my laptop when it suddenly hit me: This is what I wanted to do. This is something that I would never get tired of: solving problems, finding patterns, and bringing order out of chaos.

> I’ll never forget that night when I sat staring at my laptop when it suddenly hit me: This is what I wanted to do. This is something that I would never get tired of. Solving problems, finding patterns, bringing order out of chaos.

> I’ll never forget that night when I sat staring at my laptop when it suddenly hit me: This is what I wanted to do. This is something that I would never get tired of. Solving problems. Finding patterns. Bringing order out of chaos.

If the first variation is the correct one, should I capitalize 'solving'?

Also, should I capitalize the word after the first colon ('this')?

If I should make other changes, please suggest them.

Comment: _I’ll never forget that night when I sat staring at my laptop when it suddenly hit me— this is what I wanted to do; this is something "that" I would never get tired of: solving problems; finding patterns; bringing order out of chaos_. {There are no hard and fast rules for punctuation (some might prefer _hard-and-fast_ here, for instance), and thus the sentence may variously be punctuated).

Comment: Repeating the word *when* twice in your opening is confusing.

Comment: @user405662 Why do you have 'that' in quotes?

Comment: rjaditya: You had better drop that "that". And I agree with Yosef Baskin.